# how to write a SQL script that group clients by age and supply they purchase?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, count, case, datediff

I have a question regarding a script to write in SQL Server. I have table called client with lot of clients. the table has fields like client id, supply, dob and purchase date.

I need to write a script that pull my clients and group them by age (under 18, over 18) and supply they purchase. each client has one supply but could buy it multiple times.

I created a function that gave me age based on date of birth and purchase date.

The query that I have so far is:

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(Year, dob, purchase date) AS age, fixed.Date.Year, 
    supply, client id, dob, purchase date
FROM 
    client
```

I need to pull a query that give me the following results:

```
Supply,   number of times purchased,     age
```

The issue that I have is grouping clients by age (aggregate). I don't want them to come back individually on each row, I want to group them by supply and age.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what result are You expecting, but it seems to me that CASE statement would be fine to use with group by for age.

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(Year, dob, purchase date) AS age, [Other columns]
FROM 
    client 
GROUP BY 
    CASE
     WHEN DATEDIFF(Year, dob, purchase date) < 18 THEN '<18'
     WHEN DATEDIFF(Year, dob, purchase date) >= 18 THEN '>=18'
    END, [Other columns]
```